# LinqKit with Azure DocumentDB

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use LinqKit's PredicateBuilder with Azure DocumentDB to dynamically build Where clauses for searching. For example, I have defined several SearchModel objects that provide queryable fields for a single repository.

```
 public class EmailEventSearchModel : SearchModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Search for events of a particular type
    /// </summary>
    public IList<EventType> Types { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// search for events related to a specific user
    /// </summary>
    public string User { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// search for events that occurred after this date and time (in UTC)
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? StartDateTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// search for events that occurred before this date and time (in UTC)
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? EndDateTime { get; set; }

    ....
```

These objects get converted into a predicate using PredicateBuilder and passed into my GenericRepository object that wraps DocumentDB integration:

```
    public override async Task<ISearchResult<EmailTemplate>> Get(ISearchModel model)
    {
        if(!(model is EmailTemplateSearchModel))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Expected a model of type EmailTemplateSearchModel but received {model.GetType().Name}.");

        var templateModel = model as EmailTemplateSearchModel;

        var builder = PredicateBuilder.New<EmailTemplate>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateModel.Name))
            builder = builder.And(x => x.Name.Contains(templateModel.Name));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateModel.Body))
            builder = builder.And(x => x.Body.Contains(templateModel.Body));

        if (templateModel.AccountId.HasValue)
            builder = builder.And(x => x.AccountId == templateModel.AccountId.Value);

        if (templateModel.LegacyAccountId > 0)
            builder = builder.And(x => x.LegacyAccountId == templateModel.LegacyAccountId);

        if (templateModel.EventId.HasValue)
            builder = builder.And(x => x.EventId == templateModel.EventId);

        return await Get(builder, model);
```

Inside the repository I just pass the predicate to the Queryable object:

```
            var result = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<TModel>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName), feedoptions)
            .Where(predicate)
            .AsDocumentQuery();
```

This works great when only one of the search model properties has a value to search on. However, when I have 2 or more properties (i.e. I have EventTypes to search on and a User string), I get the error `Expression with NodeType 'Invoke' is not supported.`

Are the predicates built with PredicateBuilder compatible with Azure DocumentDB's .NET SDK? If not, is there a better solution for building dynamic queries?

Comment: Do you know which two expressions resulted the error?  DocumentDB supports Dynamic LINQ.   You can download it the package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.

Comment: Its when I have a LegacyAccountId and an EventId. I think I was able to reproduce with other properties as well though.

Comment: Could you please attach here the Linq predicates constructed by the builder when you saw the error? In the meantime, have you tried using Dynamic LINQ?

Comment: @Mike Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Justin it turned out to be an error with array searching that has been resolved in the latest document clients. I now have my dynamic repository working as expected. I will upload the code to github and link later tonight

Comment: Hi @Mike is this in git?  I'm running into the same error and would like to see the code that was corrected.  Thanks

Comment: @johnnyarguelles here is a link to my github repo. I just moved my code over there. It will be MIT licensed so feel free to use it however you would like. https://github.com/sddev-dotnet/azure-cosmosdb-generic-repository